# Python output list within a list within a list to csv

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

```
data_set =[
['a1', ['b1','c1','d1'],'f1' 'g1'],
['a2', ['b2','c2','d2'],'f2' 'g2'],
['a3', ['b3','c3','d3'],'f3' 'g3']
]

header = ['a', 'b-c-d', 'f', 'g']
```

I would like to return a csv which contains only 4 items.

`each row = ['a1', ['b1','c1','d1'], 'f1', 'g1']`

```
with open("output.csv", "w") as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
    a.writerow(header)
    a.writerows(data_set)
```

Comment: illegal string in third row of data_set... 'd3' and 'g3' should be there

Comment: what type of objects are `b`, `c`, `d`? like the header, can't you join them with some string separator?

Comment: What exactly do you want the csv to look like?

Comment: when I open this with excel or splunk etc..I do not get back the format I want. I would like for each row to be: ['a', ['b', 'c', 'd'], f, g]

Comment: What exactly is the desired output (write it out), what kind of output are you getting now?

Comment: The output right now seemed to be: row 1: ['a'],  row 2:  ['b', 'c', 'd'], row 3['f']...

Comment: With the outside brackets?

Comment: When I open with excel or splunk...the row does not match with the header. Row 2 would contain: ['b1', 'c1', 'd1'] and Row 3 would contain ['f1'] instead of Row 1: 'a1', ['b1','c1','d1'], 'f1', 'g1'. This is actually a very large data set with hundred of items in each row.

Comment: You need to be more precise about whether you want brackets or not. Also, I believe you mean *columns* instead of rows in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit upon clarification:

I believe this is what you want:

```
In [18]: def flatten(item):
    ...:     if isinstance(item,list):
    ...:         return ", ".join(item)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return item
    ...:     

In [19]: with open("output.csv", "w") as fp:
    ...:     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
    ...:     a.writerow(header)
    ...:     for row in data_set:
    ...:         a.writerow((flatten(r) for r in row))
    ...:         

In [20]: cat output.csv
a   b-c-d   f   g
a1  b1, c1, d1  f1  g1
a2  b2, c2, d2  f2  g2
a3  b3, c3, d3  f3  g3
```

### Original answer:

If I understand you correctly, you mean one of two things, both of which don't seem like good ideas to me:

```
In [6]: data_set =[
   ...: ['a1', ['b1','c1','d1'],'f1', 'g1'],
   ...: ['a2', ['b2','c2','d2'],'f2', 'g2'],
   ...: ['a3', ['b3','c3','d3'],'f3', 'g3']
   ...: ]

In [7]: with open("output.csv", "w") as fp:
   ...:     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
   ...:     a.writerow(header)
   ...:     for row in data_set:
   ...:         a.writerow((str(row),))
   ...:         

In [8]: cat output.csv
a   b-c-d   f   g
['a1', ['b1', 'c1', 'd1'], 'f1', 'g1']
['a2', ['b2', 'c2', 'd2'], 'f2', 'g2']
['a3', ['b3', 'c3', 'd3'], 'f3', 'g3']
```

Or perhaps you meant:

```
In [9]: with open("output.csv", "w") as fp:
   ...:     a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
   ...:     a.writerow(header)
   ...:     for row in data_set:
   ...:         a.writerow((str(r) for r in row))
   ...:         
   ...:         

In [10]: cat output.csv
a   b-c-d   f   g
a1  ['b1', 'c1', 'd1']  f1  g1
a2  ['b2', 'c2', 'd2']  f2  g2
a3  ['b3', 'c3', 'd3']  f3  g3

In [11]:
```

Comment: Should it be a.writerow([str(r) for r in row])?